# How do you insert a variable from an android app into a web page text field

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-2.3

I've been looking for a solution to this issue for a long time. I would really appreciated any code help. coding is not my strong suit.

Comment: http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/

Comment: will that work for in an android app?

Answer (score 1):

- Your application might send this variable (I mean its value) to a **Web
  service**. (It can call a web service.)
- Your Web service might have a function which takes one parameter and 
  writes this parameter directly to **a file** that can be accessed via 
   your web page.
- Your web page can open the file and display it in its text field.

Comment: isn't that over complicating things if I have two .java pages one that you input the variables and another one that loads a web page and puts the variables in certain text fields. All in a android app. why do I would I need to have them stored in a file?